# How to make a different font in a tag inside another tag in XSL style sheet?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How can I apply a different font in an XSL for the XML looking like this

```
<text> sometext <citation> somecitation </citation> sometext </text>
```

so the citation content should be in a different font as just text.

so this is the part of my XML

`<text>`She flipped her bed over and found invisible alligators all over her room. `<citation>` What's going on here? `<citation>` she demanded. `</text>`

I wrote a code `<xsl:template match="text">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> 
            <q>
                <xsl:value-of select="citation/text()"/>
            </q> 
        </p>`
(q stands for italic in CSS)
What I want to get : 
She flipped her bed over and found invisible alligators all over her room.
*"What's going on here?"* she demanded.

What I get for now : She flipped her bed over and found invisible alligators all over her room.she demanded. *"What's going on here?"*

how can I proceed to get correct result?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show some code sample that you have problems with? I don't understand the problem. Just assign a different css class for the somexxx elements and then use different fonts in the css

Comment: I have something like this in the xsl  
           <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> 
                <q>
                     <xsl:value-of select="citation/text()"/>
               </q>
          
        </p>   but the citation is inside the text, this code gives me the whole text at first and then all citations.

Comment: What is the output of your transformation? HTML? XSL-FO? ePub? Do you actually know what you want the transformation to produce?

Comment: @MichaelKay it is HTML. I have some xml containing a text with a citations inside it, so these citations should go in <q>...</q>, but all the other text not.

Comment: If your output is HTML, why don't you use CSS to specify the font to be used for each element (as already suggested above)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k the problem is not in CSS! the problem is in the order!!! I get correct font but in the false order, so for the example in my question I get :   She flipped her bed over and found invisible alligators all over her room. she demanded  "What's going on here?"       The question is how to proceed such citations correct.

Comment: @Aleksandra If you tell CSS to style `citation` as italic (or any other style), then only citations will be so styled. Post a [mcve] if you want an demonstration of how this works.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I edited my question, can you understand my problem now? I am not allowed to change CSS, I should only write xsl.

Comment: Your main problem is that your XSLT code is incorrect. That has nothing to do with fonts. You need separate templates for `text` and for `citation`, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the default styling applied by the browser should be quite sufficient -  provided you use the correct HTML tags.

Given the following input:

**XML**

```
<text>She flipped her bed over and found invisible alligators all over her room. <citation> What's going on here? </citation> she demanded. </text>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="citation">
    <cite>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </cite>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>She flipped her bed over and found invisible alligators all over her room. <cite> What's going on here? </cite> she demanded. 
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

which most any browser will render as:

[image]

---

If you don't like or don't trust the browser defaults, you can specify your own style, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="citation">
    <span style="font-style: italic;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                q {
                    font-style: italic;;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="citation">
    <q>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </q>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```